# Why does jQuery's load() require extra code? What should this extra code be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modularity

In my index.html, I have a bunch of empty section tags.  Each section tag receives its respective HTML code from a separate file.  My setup looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Using jQuery's load()</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="section1"></section>
    <section id="section2"></section>
    <section id="section3"></section>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/section-loader.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**section1.html**

```
<h1>Section 1</h1>
```

**section2.html**

```
<h2>Section 2</h2>
```

**section3.html**

```
<h3>Section 3</h3>
```

**section-loader.js**

```
$('#section1').load('section1.html');
$('#section2').load('section2.html');
$('#section3').load('section3.html');
```

When I first load everything, it loads the HTML for each section into their respective section tags in index.html.  This is exactly what I want to have happen.

However, when I refresh the page or open up a new instance of it, none of these load calls happen.

I added an alert to section-loader.js to see if the page was being called that second time, and I received unexpected results.  The alert caused everything to run the second time exactly the way I wanted (except with an unwanted alert).

I hope I have explained this well enough.  It is very strange behavior to me.

I have two questions:

- Why is this happening?
- What is the best way to fix it?

Comment: What happens in the "Network" tab after the reload (devtools)?

Comment: Try running the code in `section-loader.js` inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @OddDev nothing but 200s

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't work. just causes none of the sections to load.

Comment: @Barmar it should be OK as long as sections are placed before the script in HTML source.

Comment: @SalmanA That's what I thought, but it seems like there's some weird timing thing going on. Since it only happens the second time, I suspect it also involves the cache.

Comment: Is there a live site we can see this happening on? This kind of thing can't be reproduced with jsfiddle.

Comment: Uhhh...can you point me to a site that can hold it? Or is there a way I can just share a project in a zipped folder?

Comment: @Evorlor Could you please disable the cache in the devtools (F12 -> cog -> Tick "Disable Cache (while DevTools is open)" for Chrome) and do the reload again *while* DevTools are still open?

Comment: @OddDev I never got it working.  I gave up, and just stuck everything in index.html :( Thank you for your help, though

Answer (score -1):

You must wait onload event, for jQuery this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#section1').load('section1.html');
    $('#section2').load('section2.html');
    $('#section3').load('section3.html');
});
```

Comment: This isn't `onload` event but shorthand for jQuery `ready` pseudo event

Comment: Doesn't work. just causes none of the sections to load.

Comment: @Evorlor it works! http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07646156934735811693